# What are the practical uses for strings?

Tags: string

I have been following some Fortran tutorials online and have recently come across strings. I was just wondering... what are the practical uses of them? It's probably just a beginner's oversight, but I just can't think of any projects you can do with strings. Please, enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are... everywhere, and in everything. Have a look at the [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) tag for >100,000 examples.

Strings are how you store text, like how integers and reals are how you store numbers. So anywhere you want to work with words you need strings.

Even in the simplest of programs, [`hello world`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program), the `"Hello, World!"` is a string. And the ultimate test for computers, [the Turing Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) is dependent on strings to work.

If you want some practice projects, just do a web search for "string problems" or similar. You'll get hundreds of pages of example problems.